# iPhone caption camera, imageview does not show picture taken

Tags: iphone, ios6, camera, picker

I was asked to make an app that gave random captions about their cat. I have 2 problems and I followed tutorials step by step and nothing worked. 1. When ever a picture is taken or selected, it does not show up in the UIImageView, every thing is liked up in the storyboard I just don't get it. Also, I have an IBAction made where it makes the random caption and it works fine when its pressed by a button, is there anyway where the caption will display automaticly when a picture is either taken or selected? Here is my Code in the .M file. Im a beginner when it comes to makeing apps.

```
#import "Generator.h"

@interface Generator ()

@end

@implementation Generator

-(IBAction)TakePhoto{
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
-(IBAction)ChooseExisting{
    picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker2.delegate = self;
    [picker2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentViewController:picker2 animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(IBAction)Back{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(IBAction)random {
    int text = rand() % 10;
    switch (text) {
        case 0:
            textview.text = @"I'd Say About Average";
            break;
        case 1:
            textview.text = @"Happy but Hideous";
            break;
        case 2:
            textview.text = @"Furrific";
            break;
        case 3:
            textview.text = @"Cuddly";
            break;
        case 4:
            textview.text = @"Abby Normal";
            break;
        case 5:
            textview.text = @"Purrty";
            break;
        case 6:
            textview.text = @"Yuck";
            break;
        case 7:
            textview.text = @"Glowing";
            break;
        case 8:
            textview.text = @"AWWWWWW";
            break;
        case 9:
            textview.text = @"The Cutest";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

any help will do. my SDK is iOS 6.1

Comment: Your code above has no imageView.
What are you trying to do here?
image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

Comment: "image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];"  What is image? it should be `urImageView.image = ...`

Comment: what is the meathod for setting the picture taken to the imageview i Have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

image is autoreleased. Set your imageView before it goes out of scope, or retain it. If you have it hooked up to anything, it should stay in memory and show.